# Vector of linked list

Tags: java, vector, collections, linked-list

How to create vector of linked list in Java using Collections?
So far I have written the following code:

```
Vector <LinkedList <Integer> > adj = new Vector<>();
```

However I am unable to figure out how to initialize the vector with head nodes of the linked list.

What I want is given an integer `N`, I wish to initialize the vector with the values `0` to `N-1` as the head nodes:

```
e.g given N = 4

vector ---> 0
            1
            2
            3
```

So that later I can add members to the list when needed like :

```
vector ---> 0->2->3
            1->3
            2->0->1
            3->1
```

Comment: You create a `Vector` as you have done and then add as many empty `LinkedList` objects as you need.  But first, why are you using a `Vector`?  This smells an awful lot like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: This is an explanation to @JimGarrison's comment wrt. `Vector`. From the Javadoc of `Vector`:  ["If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Answer (score 1):

With the code you have written, you have created an empty vector - you have to fill it with desired number of LinkedList *instances* (I am guessing you are a C++ programmer, where the vector would initialize "automatically"?). E.g. initialize your vector like this:

```
int N = 4;
Vector<LinkedList<Integer>> adj = new Vector<>(N); // N here isn't really needed, but it sets the initial capacity of the vector
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ajd.add(new LinkedList<>());
}
```

Also, as Turing85 pointed out, you should use `ArrayList` if you don't need the synchronization.